# how to create android popup window?

Tags: android, popup, window, floating

I am trying to create a popup/floating window in my app. like the android app switcher when you long press the home key. It doesnt really count as an activity.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: There are lot of tutorials out there if you just google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello please search before asking go here nice tuto http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: He asked for a PopUpWindow, not Dialog